# keep getting these error messege "The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type AppWidgetProvider"

Tags: android, android-widget

> The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type AppWidgetProvider

```
public class SupermarioActivity<imageButton1> extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static SupermarioActivity Widget = null;
public static Context context;
public static AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
public static int appWidgetIds[];   

@Override
public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )    {     
    if (null == context) context = SupermarioActivity.context;
    if (null == appWidgetManager) appWidgetManager = SupermarioActivity.appWidgetManager;
    if (null == appWidgetIds) appWidgetIds = SupermarioActivity.appWidgetIds;

    SupermarioActivity.Widget = this;
    SupermarioActivity.context = context;
    SupermarioActivity.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    SupermarioActivity.appWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;

    Log.i("PXR", "onUpdate");


    }

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId) {


    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton1, appWidgetId);


    // Tell the widget manager
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    

    imageButton1 imagebutton1 = (imageButton1) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
         ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
         iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
    });
}

    private void setContentView(int main) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
    private imageButton1 findViewById(int imagebutton1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Please review your question before posting it. There were "enter your code here" lines in there for instance, hardly seems like you've put in some effort? Also: there is no body to your question, don't you think it might look better if you actually type _some_ text? Like: "I'm trying to do X, but my IDE says Y if I do Z. This is (partof) my code. If it's about the oncreate, and it still shows this behaviour if e.g. the updatecode is gone, please leave that out!

Comment: im new at this im trying to make a widget that plays a little animation when you click it i know there must be a lot of mistakes but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: But you might have asked for help before? Being new at this doesn't mean you can just leave pieces of text that say "enter your code here" that came from clicking one of the editor buttons in your question? Also, it is common sense (nothing to do with programming) that if you want to ask a question and expect help, you might as well be civil about it and actually do some introduction, instead of just putting code down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined an `onCreate(Bundle)` method for `SupermarioActivity<imageButton1>` that looks like it belongs in an `Activity` subclass. But `SupermarioActivity` extends `AppWidgetProvider`, not `Activity` (or any `Activity` subclass).

Comment: how would i go about making an app that holds widgets inside

Comment: @GeorgeP - There's a nice intro to widgets in the developer guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's pretty straightforward: the class `AppWidgetProvider` does not seem to have a method `onCreate(Bundle)`.

> A convenience class to aid in implementing an AppWidget provider.
>   Everything you can do with AppWidgetProvider, you can do with a
>   regular BroadcastReceiver. **AppWidgetProvider merely parses the
>   relevant fields out of the Intent that is received in
>   onReceive(Context,Intent), and calls hook methods with the received
>   extras.**

(emph mine, from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html )

If I was a paperclip, I might have posted:

*It looks like you are trying to make an `Activity`? Would you like to:*
- *Extend the activity class?*

Answer (score 0):

Just put extends Activity on your class